# Socket.io rooms is not sending message to specific users

Tags: react-native, express, sockets, socket.io

I'm developing React Native Expo app on which I added socket.io to handle real time events.

I want user A to make a purchase to user B, and when user B accepts the purchase, instantaneously user A should receive a message on his end that the purchase was approved.

I check the socket.io documentation and many similar questions regarding this but I don't understand why I can not make it work

BACKEND:

```
    function purchaseNotification(io) {

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        socket.on('joinRoom', roomName => {
            socket.join(roomName);
        });
            
            socket.on('purchaseCompleted', data => {
                io.to(data.userId).emit('purchaseConfirmation', data.message);
                socket.to(data.userId).emit('purchaseConfirmation', data.message);// tried this too     
        });

      })
     }
    
    module.exports = purchaseNotification;
```

FRONTEND USER A:

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
      const userId = 'd48d76e6-a733-4d6c-aab7-48525ea44294';
      socket.emit('joinRoom', userId);
      socket.on('purchaseConfirmation', (data) => console.log(data))
    }, [])
```

FRONTEND USER B:

```
const deliveryConfirmed = () => {
        const data = {
            userId: 'd48d76e6-a733-4d6c-aab7-48525ea44294',
            message: 'Purchase completed'
        }
        socket.emit('purchaseCompleted', data)
    }
```

I consoled log on the backend roomName, and data from purchaseCompleted and I'm receiving all the data correctly to the backend.

Comment: Is that UUID one that you made up?  As far as I know, socket.io socket IDs are 20 alphanumeric characters.  That's what needs to be in the `socket.to` call.

Comment: @TimRoberts - The OP is using the userId value as a room name, not as an actual socket.io id.  Room names can be any string you want to use so that part looks OK to me.

Comment: I was thinking there is maybe some async issue but I'm not sure at this point